# Streamline Rspec Test of Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am currently testing a Rails(4.2) helper with Rspec(3) successfully. However, the test file setup is a bit cumbersome. How can I streamline the require and/or include lines?

```
# spec/helpers/nav_helper_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../../app/helpers/nav_helper' # this seems bulky

describe NavHelper do
  include NavHelper # this seems repetitive
  ...
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "default" setup you probably have a `rails_helper` in addition to your `spec_helper`. If you don't mind loading all of the Rails directories in this one spec (a bit of a performance hit) you can require that instead of the `spec_helper` (cleaning up the requires). But there's nothing wrong with including only what you need, it will run faster.

Rspec will also mix in the helper for you if it knows the spec type. You can either include `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` in your spec helper, or include the type in the `describe` declaration:

```
describe NavHelper, type: :helper do
```

Either way you'll be able to use something like `expect(helper.method_name).to eq(result)` without explicitly including the module.

Comment: I have that config line already, and whether or not I specify the type, the helper module's methods aren't available unless I specifically include. Also, it seems that at least I should have to `require_relative`. All this has worked more cleanly in another app, but I can't see the different. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Make sure that your file is named correctly and is in the correct directory: see [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec)

Comment: It is. I've updated the example with the file name/location. Sorry for my delayed responses!

Comment: Sounds like you either don't have a rails helper file or that file isn't including the full environment

Comment: Hmmm... Could you point me toward the configuration that includes the full environment?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/install/templates/spec/rails_helper.rb) is the rspec-rails install template, it includes the env at the top

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. Yes, I have both of those things already.